# How do I plot linear regression results if input and target have different sizes?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

For a linear regression model that I conducted, I'd like to review the regression plot of results. But since I have an input of size 6 parameters and target (output therefore) of 4, I get error when I use this code : [source code](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382550/plot-sklearn-linearregression-output-with-matplotlib&ved=2ahUKEwi4667ppJncAhXGkSwKHVPEAb0QFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3ecBTfVKDS90iW0g6qbWAM)

```
pyplot.scatter(x_train, y_train)
pyplot.plot(np.sort(x_values, axis=0,prediction)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: You want to scatter data with more than 3 dimensions??

Comment: @AndreasLook No but there should be a measure of correctness of the regression analysis at the end

Comment: You can use different plot for each target.

Answer (score 2):

You can plot your residuals. I am sorry I can't write it in Python but in R you would do it like this:

```
plot(my.model$residuals)
```

This will give you a scatterplot that you WANT to look like a null plot. Any curve or pattern in the points means that your model is not a good fit.

If you are interested in assessing each variable's prediction power I recommend (because you only have six) doing 1 regression model on each variable *by itself* and then plotting the residuals of those models, again looking for a null plot. You can also look at the correlation of each predictor variable vs your response variable. Those with higher correlation will be better predictors.